# Text Slider Carousel height transition?

Tags: jquery, css

The height of the slider changes according to the text in the background how can we add transition or animation effect with CSS or jquery so it doesn't happen in an instance and doesn't look odd like in this case.
I tried `hasClass` and then `fadein` but it didn't work.

Here is the jsfiddle code
https://jsfiddle.net/39amxqjd/30

```
<div class="testimonial-section">
    <div class="paralax-overlay">
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row wow">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown delay-07s">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h3>

                            <span>

                            </span>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-8 wow fadeInUp delay-07s">
                    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="indecator">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#indecator">
                            </li>
                            <li class="" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#indecator">
                            </li>
                            <li class="" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#indecator">
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner full_display" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item sngl-testimonial active">
                                <div class="sngle-tsmt">
                                    <div class="client-dsc">
                                        <h3 style="color: #fff;">dsfdsf</h3>
                                        <p style="font-size: 19px;">
                                             fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd 

                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item sngl-testimonial">
                                <div class="sngle-tsmt">
                                    <div class="client-dsc">
                                         <br><br><br>
                                        <h3 style="color: #fff; font-size: 26px;">sfdsdfds</h3>

                                        <p style="font-size: 19px;">
                                            fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd 
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item sngl-testimonial">
                                <div class="sngle-tsmt">
                                    <div class="client-dsc">
                                        <h3 style="color: #fff; font-size: 26px;">sdfsfsd</h3>
                                        <p style="font-size: 19px;">
                                            fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd 
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left left_twit_crousel_btn" data-slide="prev" href="#indecator" role="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left">
                            </i>
                            <span class="sr-only">
                                Previous
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right right_twit_crousel_btn" data-slide="next" href="#indecator" role="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right">
                            </i>
                            <span class="sr-only">
                                Next
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<script
```

Comment: you can use min-height for it!

Comment: if i give it height then it doesn't look good on smaller screen sizes. I want it to resize but with animation

Comment: did you solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to do it like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var height=$('#s1').height()+20;
     $(".carousel-inner").css("height", height);  //initial heigth
 });


$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {    
   var height=$($(e.relatedTarget).height());   
   $(".carousel-inner").css("height", height[0]);
});
```

```css
.title{
  text-align:center;
}

.carousel-inner{
    height: 0;
    transition: height 800ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.26, 1.38);
}

.para{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;
   padding-left:8.5em;
   padding-right:8.5em;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-right:before{   
    background-color: #85238A;
    padding: .3rem 0.75rem;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left:before{   
    background-color: #85238A;
    padding: .3rem 0.75rem;
}

.carousel-control.right{
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0) 100%);
     opacity: 1;
}
 
.carousel-control.left{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-inner{
   color:white;   
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div id="s1" class="item active">
       <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
       <p class="para">
                                             fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd end 

                                        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="s2" class="item">
       <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
      <p class="para">
                                             fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd fsdfdsfsd end  
                                        </p>
    </div>    
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[My Codepen Example here](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/bxMJqm)